# Is the expression 'half a percent' acceptable in formal English?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, idioms

When central banks raise or lower interest rates the radio announcer will say for example:

> an increase of one half of one percent

Informally people use *half a percent* instead, which is less wordy, but is it also incorrect?  [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=half%20a%20percent,half%20of%20one%20percent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) analysis shows publishers favour the longer version, although the short form seems to be gaining some traction.

Thinking about it, I'd never offer someone *one half of one pizza*; that sounds weird.  However, I believe *of* is necessary here, in combination with an article, quantifier or pronoun.  Is this correct?

Comment: it does seem to be accepted and understood, but it never really made any sense to me either, because percent is a ratio of two things and is not a unit per se.

Comment: @horatio: Physicist sometime treat "percent" exactly as a unit, albeit a dimensionless one. This does not bother us; indeed "radians" is another pure number that is used as a unit.

Comment: Most announcers I know say "50 basis points" or "50 points" to mean 0.5%.

Comment: @horatio, you are right in that when someone says "half a percent" in this way they almost invariably mean "half a percentage point": that is to say, that interest rates have risen from 1.0 to 1.5% rather than 1.0 to 1.005%; the former is of course a rise of 50%.

Comment: @horatio: percent can be used to define a ratio, but it is not defined as such. The *Bureau International
des Poids et Mesures* simply defines % as a representation of the number 0.01. See this document, at page 50 (or 140 if you can't understand French, but bare in mind the French version is more extensive): http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8.pdf

Comment: i understand all these points, but percent is per cent conjoined, and the ratio is implicit in the meaning of the word despite stricter scientific definitions. i fully accept the use and meaning, but it still doesn't strictly make sense to me :)

Comment: @nico I agree, and nobody would say 'half a pi' or 'quarter a 0.1'.

Comment: I think it's perfectly acceptable, and that the difference is more in terms of style. "One half of one percent" puts more emphasis on the amount being small, with oral stress falling on both ones, '*one* half of *one* percent'.

Comment: You're probably encountering example of a style and usage guide colouring output. Most media houses have style and usage guides which dictate preferred and mandatory forms. This would undoubtedly be one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: **yes, “half a percent” is accepted usage**, even in formal writing.

To back it up: the *New Oxford American English* lists *percent* as both an adverb (*“a 1.8 percent increase”*) and a noun (*“a reduction of half a percent or so in price”*). Note that the second example nicely answers your question.

Answer (score 9):

The phrase *half a(n) X* is a well-established English idiom. The use of *percent* here is a straightforward application of the idiom:

- half a cup of water
- half a loaf of bread
- half a dozen
- half a percent

In financial contexts, the more formal version may be preferred, but there's nothing wrong with the informal equivalent.

Comment: Also note that the article can precede "half" in this kind of construction: "Today the Dow Jones Industrial Average fell a half percent." Or, "He brought home a half dozen roses."

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

People in the financial world will sometimes say 50 basis points (itself often shortened to 50 bips in speech). A basis point is one percent of one percent.

But in colloquial, mainstream English, half a percent is perfectly fine.

PW

Answer (score 1):

As 'per cent' means 'of a hundred', it would be best to say 'a half percent'.  The newsreader version is unnecessarily wordy.